# Is "school" a preposition in "The School day never goes too slowly"?

Tags: prepositions, nouns, parts-of-speech, attributive-nouns

Is School a preposition in this sentence?: The School day never goes too slowly. If it is not what part of speech is it?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a preposition.  "School day" is a compound noun.  In this case it is the combination of two nouns (school+day), but can also be the combination of multiple different elements (i.e., noun+verb, adverb+noun, etc.).  Compound nouns are sometimes written as two separate words (e.g., "bus stop"), as a hyphenated work (e.g., dry-cleaning), or as a single word (e.g., bedroom).  In fact, you will sometime see it written as "schoolday."

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a preposition.

In this use, "school day" is a compound noun.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically than it being a compound noun, or noun phrase, we can say what the role of *school* is in *school day*. It is an ***adjunct noun***, or ***attributive noun***. It is describing the *sort* of day being spoken of.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered correctly already. "School" is not a preposition. "The School day" is a compound noun.

Collins Dictionary [www.collinsdictionary.com] defines a preposition as:  A preposition is a word such as 'by', 'for', 'into', or 'with' which usually has a noun group as its object."

You can browse a full, comprehensive list of all English prepositions on the web at www.thefreedictionary.com